# What are geometry-adaptive kernels?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

I was reading a paper "CSRNet: Dilated Convolutional Neural Networks for Understanding the Highly
Congested Scenes" and found this term but couldn't find the exact meaning of geometry-adaptive kernels.Can someone please explain me this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geometric algorithms are based on geometric objects such as points, lines and circles. The term *kernel* refers to a collection of representations for constant-size geometric objects and operations on these representations. The term *adaptive kernel*, in a broad sense, means that these representations are not immutable or fixed, but rather that they can vary according to some criteria.